# Enable a USB WIFI Dongle in Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, wifi, usb-device

I have an issue with my laptops' `WIFI`

Whenever I connect the home network, the whole machine freezes. I came across drivers to try and fix the problem but I though it is better to use a compatible `USB WIFI Dongle` that provides better speed than the inbuilt adapter.

The question is, how can I disable the built in and use the USB WIFI Dongle by default?

Please advise me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Bios or Hardware kill switch

You can do this in bios if at all your computer supports this. If your computer has a kill switch for wireless, you can also opt for that.

## Blacklist driver

You could blacklist the driver.

1. **Look up your Card Name.**

   First, identify your Built-in Adapter Name. Remove the Plugged-in USB Wifi Dongle.
   Then run:

   `ifconfig | grep wl`

   The grep Command refines the output List showing only the Entries matching the Keyword.
2. **Discovering Wireless Driver**

   Now to find out the Wireless Kernel Module in use, Run:

   `readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver`

   Possibly replace “wlan0” with the identifier found in the former step.
3. **Disabling Wifi Adapter**

   To Turn Off Wireless interface, unload the kernel module with:

   `sudo modprobe -r [MYMOD]`

   Replace with the current one in the above Command. So for instance:

   `sudo modprobe -r wl`

   Finally, to make the change permanent then Blacklist it editing:

   `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

   And appending the blacklisted Network Interface Module as below:

   `blacklist wl`

   **Ctrl+x** to Save & Exit from nano Editor.

## lscpi

You can also use lscpi command.

```
lscpi -k
```

`lspci -k` will list all `PCI*` devices and their drivers. To blacklist add the line below to in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist drivername
```

This Requires root privilege. Then reboot. The driver won't load if blacklisted. No driver means the interface won't show up in the network commands.